ADS124S08 not displaying appropriate result
SETUP :
The ADS124S08 chip has been soldered onto a breakout board, it has been connected to an Arduino UNO R3 via a breadboard.
The pin out is specified as below:
Pin out description 
As for the other pins, this is the pin out configuration according to the data sheet:
pin configuration according to datasheet
CODE :
The code that I have written on the arduino with the objective of reading the differential voltage between AN0 and AN1 pins. It is provided below:
#include <SPI.h>  // SPI library

// Pin Definitions
const int CS_PIN = 10;     // Chip Select pin
const int DRDY_PIN = 9;    // Data Ready pin
const int RESET_PIN = 8;   // Reset pin

// ADS124S08 Commands
#define RESET_CMD 0x06     // Reset command
#define START_CMD 0x08     // Start continuous conversion
#define STOP_CMD  0x0A     // Stop conversion
#define WREG_CMD  0x40     // Write to registers
#define RDATA_CMD 0x12     // Read data

void setup() {
  // Initialize pins
  pinMode(CS_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DRDY_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(RESET_PIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Set SPI settings
  SPI.begin(); 
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1)); // 1 MHz, CPOL = 0, CPHA = 1
  
  // Reset the ADS124S08
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(RESET_CMD);  // Send reset command
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);
  delay(5); // Wait for reset to complete

  // Disable IDAC (Current Sources) - Not needed for voltage measurement
  writeRegister(0x04, 0x00);  // Disable IDAC

  // Set the input multiplexer to measure a specific voltage input (e.g., AIN0 as positive input and AIN1 as negative input for differential measurement)
  writeRegister(0x03, 0x01);  // Set input channels to AIN0 and AIN1 (differential input mode)

  // Set PGA gain (for voltage signals, select a gain based on your expected voltage range, e.g., Gain = 1 for larger voltages)
  writeRegister(0x01, 0x00);  // Set gain to 1 (no amplification)

  // Start continuous conversions
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(START_CMD);  // Send start conversion command
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  // Wait for DRDY to go low, indicating data is ready
  if (digitalRead(DRDY_PIN) == LOW) {
    // Read data from ADS124S08
    long adcValue = readADC();
    Serial.println(adcValue);  // Output the ADC value to the serial monitor
  }
}

void writeRegister(byte reg, byte value) {
  // Function to write to ADS124S08 registers
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(WREG_CMD | (reg & 0x0F));  // Write register command
  SPI.transfer(0x00);                      // Write only one register
  SPI.transfer(value);                     // Write the data
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);
}

long readADC() {
  // Function to read data from ADS124S08
  long result = 0;
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(RDATA_CMD);  // Send read data command
  
  // Read 24 bits (3 bytes) from the ADC
  result |= ((long)SPI.transfer(0x00) << 16);  // Read first byte
  result |= ((long)SPI.transfer(0x00) << 8);   // Read second byte
  result |= SPI.transfer(0x00);                // Read third byte
  digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);

  // Check for negative values (sign extension)
  if (result & 0x800000) {
    result |= 0xFF000000;  // Sign-extend negative numbers
  }

  return result;
}

OUTPUT :
The output is either not displayed or shows the value 0, which is the default value of the "result = 0" parameter.
I want to ultimately verify if my ADS124S08 is working properly or not, and solve this specific issue.
I tried the above code and setup.
I am expecting the result to be displayed as a proper byte reading instead of 0.

An SPI transaction consists of setting up an SPI transaction with SPI.beginTransaction(), select the chip with CS pin, followed by one or more data transfer, and deselect the chip select, and end the transaction with SPI.endTransaction(). Your writeRegister() and readADC() functions doesn't have a complete SPI transaction.
